# glassfish specified library jar mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar does not exist

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, glassfish

I configured the `JDBC Ressources` in `GlassFish` and I pinged it and it was successful. But when I try to deploy the EJB module I get this error:

```
Grave:   Exception while deploying the app [BanqueEJBPersistence] : Specified library jar mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar does not exist: C:\Program%20Files\NetBeans%208.0.2\ide\modules\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar
```

I am working on NetBeans 8.0.2 and GlassFish 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting your mysql jar at `{Glass Fish Server Location}/glassfish/lib` If it is already there, it might be a Netbeans thing. Directly add it through Netbeans using the add Connection wizard under Services -> Databases.